# Saving to CoreData seems to be working but it doesn't Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Saving my user to CoreData appears to be saving as  the `do catch` saving block doesn't throw any error and I actually do get the success print in it, but then when loading saved user is not  found. 
I noticed it because when I launch the app, at login it downloads the user from firebase every time. 
Basically the whole logic is:

Login calls `User.findUser()` this will look for user in CoreData
if found it will simply load user details and continue, else will call `Firebase.downloadUserDetails()` that will look for user in Firebase ( in this case it means that is the first time user launch the app on the device ). If found it will download user's details and call `User.saveUserDetails()` that will save user to CoreData. So at the next login it should be found. Well if I re run the app after this, `User.findUser()` still won't find any users and start the whole process again.

I didn't realised it before as the `User.saveUserDetails()` doesn't print any error while saving, but I added a check for any `User` record in CoreData and it always shows 0

Can you see what's happening? How do I check if I properly set CoreData in AppDelegate?

This is the saving function:

```
static func saveUserDetails(completed: @escaping(Bool) -> (),userId: String, fcmToken: String, email: String, fullName: String, familyName: String, givenName: String, profileImage: UIImage, address: String, city: String, zipCode: String, region: String, country: String, phoneNumber: String) {

        let context = AppDelegate.viewContext
        //check if user is already in database
        let request: NSFetchRequest<User> = User.fetchRequest()

        // check for any existing records in CoreData
        print("check for any existing records in CoreData")
        do {
            let fetchPre = try context.fetch(request)
            print("saveUserDetails: Users saved in CoreData are: \(fetchPre.count)")

            for user in fetchPre {
                print("User id is : \(String(describing: user.userId))")
                print("User name is : \(String(describing: user.fullName))")
            }
        } catch  {
            print(" Error fetching user during saving : \(error)")
        }


        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "userId == %@", userId)
        //        request.fetchLimit = 1
        do {
            let fetch = try context.fetch(request)
            print("saveUserDetails: fetch is \(fetch.count)")
            for value in fetch {
                print(" User/saveUserDetails:   checking for existing user")
                if userId == value.userId {
                    print("   user is already saved ")
                    // save changes in database
//                    value.setValue(userId, forKey: "userId")
                    value.setValue(fcmToken, forKey: "fcmToken")
                    value.setValue(fullName, forKey: "fullName")
                    value.setValue(familyName, forKey: "familyName")
                    value.setValue(givenName, forKey: "givenName")
                    value.setValue(address, forKey: "address")
                    value.setValue(city, forKey: "city")
                    value.setValue(region, forKey: "region")
                    value.setValue(zipCode, forKey: "zipCode")
                    value.setValue(country, forKey: "country")
                    value.setValue(phoneNumber, forKey: "phoneNumber")
                    value.setValue(email, forKey: "email")
                    //                    return
                } else {
                    print(" User/saveUserDetails: user is new")
                    //create user in database
                    let user = User(context: context)
                    user.userId = userId
                    user.fcmToken = fcmToken
                    user.fullName = fullName
                    user.familyName = familyName
                    user.givenName = givenName
                    user.address = address
                    user.zipCode = zipCode
                    user.city = city
                    user.region = region
                    user.country = country
                    user.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
                    user.profilePicture = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImage, 1.0)! as NSData

                }

                do {
                    // save changes in database
                    try context.save()
                    print("  User/saveUserDetails: user is saved")
                    completed(true)
                } catch  {
                    print("Error saving user details : \(error)")
                }
            }
        } catch  {
            print(" Error fetching user during saving : \(error)")

        }

    }
```

Comment: A lot of code and a very vague question. Have you tried to debug this to get a better understanding of what is happening?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I reformatted the question and modified the sample code, it was actually a bit too long..now the `saveUserDetails()`function performs a check to look for any `User` record and even when saving again it doesn't find any. I don't really understand why.. no errors are thrown so it looks like is actually saving..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a logical bug in your code, right now you do

```
let fetch = try context.fetch(request)
for value in fetch {
    if userId == value.userId {
    ...
    } else {
    ...
}
```

Since you have a predicate for your request, "userId == %@", userId, the `for` loop will only be entered if a user is found with the given id which means the `else` part can never be executed and no new user created.
I
So instead of a `for` loop I would suggest something like

```
if let user = fetch.first { //I assume the predicate means we get one or zero users back
    //Handle user update
} else {
    //Handle new user
}
```

Comment: Absolutely!! Thank you so much for pointing it out. I was lost in the function and could not see it. Works perfectly now.